# Problem with the gradients for a tensor flow training

Tags: tensorflow, loss-function, eager-execution, gradienttape

I am training a linear tensorflow model with a custom additional loss which depends on some inner derivatives. The NN recieves an input (x,y) and gives the output (u, v) with some hidden layers in between. I use implicit differentiation to add the u_x (derivative of u with respect to x) and v_y (analagously) to the loss of the function.

I made this function

```
def continuous_equation_constraint(features):
    """Calculate the constraint based on the current prediction of the nueral network. 
        It should one should ideally always have u_x + v_y = 0.

    Args:
        x (tf.Tensor): Position data
        y (tf.Tensor): Time data

    Returns:
        float value: The value given by the constraint equation for the given values of 
        x and y and the current state of the network.
    """
    
    features = features

    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=False) as tape:
        tape.watch(features)
        prediction = model(features)
        
    grads = tape.jacobian(prediction, features)

    # n = grads.numpy()
    
    u_x = tf.constant([grads[i,0,i,0].numpy() for i in range(len(features))], dtype=tf.float32)
    v_y = tf.constant([grads[i,1,i,1].numpy() for i in range(len(features))], dtype=tf.float32)

    
    constraint = tf.add(u_x, v_y)                 # This should be equal to 0
    
    
    return constraint
```

which works fine and I can train my netwrok. This however didnt allow me to use @tf.function due to the use of numpy. Therefore I wrote the following function:

```
def continuous_equation_constraint(features):
    features = features

    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=False) as tape:
        tape.watch(features)
        prediction = model(features)
        
    grads = tape.jacobian(prediction, features)
    l = len(features)
    features_tensor = tf.constant([i for i in range(l)])

    # Create a tensor containing the first and third dimension indices
    # with an additional axis to match the required format for 'tf.gather_nd'.
    indices = tf.stack([features_tensor, tf.zeros_like(features_tensor),
                        features_tensor, tf.zeros_like(features_tensor)], axis=1)

    # Gather the required elements from 'grads'
    u_x = tf.gather_nd(grads, indices)

    indices = tf.stack([features_tensor, tf.ones_like(features_tensor),
                        features_tensor, tf.ones_like(features_tensor)], axis=1)
    v_y = tf.gather_nd(grads, indices)
    # Convert 'u_x' to float32 (if needed)
    u_x = tf.cast(u_x, tf.float32)
    v_y = tf.cast(v_y, tf.float32)

    
    constraint = tf.add(u_x, v_y)                 # This should be equal to 0
    
    
    return constraint
```

Which uses only tensorflow operations, allowing the use of tf.function.

Now however with this new function the network ist training properly. I compared the outputs of the functions (the losses) and they are always the same, but the calculated gradients are different...
the gradients are applied as shown below:

```
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape2:
        prediction = model(features)
        model_loss = mse(labels, prediction)
        constraint_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(continuous_equation_constraint(features)))
        complete_loss = tf.add(model_loss, constraint_loss)
       

    gradients = tape2.gradient(complete_loss, model.trainable_weights)


    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_weights))
```

I want to use the tf.funciton to improve the training speed but for some reason when I do, the traing loss goes down super fast and doesnt really learn anything.

Thanks for the help!

I made the following function which again has the same results for all losses but still gives a different gradient...

```
def continuous_equation_constraint3(features):
        """Calculate the constraint based on the current prediction of the nueral network. 
                It should one should ideally always have u_x + v_y = 0.

        Args:
                x (tf.Tensor): Position data
                y (tf.Tensor): Time data

        Returns:
                float value: The value given by the constraint equation for the given values of 
                x and y and the current state of the network.
        """

        features = features
        x = tf.cast(features[:,0], tf.float32)
        y = tf.cast(features[:,1], tf.float32)
    
       
        with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
                tape.watch(x)
                tape.watch(y)
                x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 1])
                y = tf.reshape(y, [-1, 1])
                pos = tf.concat([x,y], axis=1)
                prediction = model(pos)
                u = prediction[:,0]
                v = prediction[:,1]
                u_x = tape.gradient(u,x)
                v_y = tape.gradient(v,y)
                       

        constraint = tf.add(u_x, v_y)                 # This should be equal to 0

        return constraint
```